# How often is the duplicate target link clicked?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, statistics

Can we get some stats about how often is the duplicate target link clicked on questions marked as a duplicate? I'm particularly interested in duplicate questions with answers, because on those without answers anonymous users get automatically redirected to the duplicate target.

I think it's important that people who visit a question marked as a duplicate visit also the duplicate targets, because duplicate targets are often canonical questions with better quality answers.

Comment: We don't track who visits what beyond requests logged by our front-end load balancer, and that's actually a new table every day - not sure if I can go far enough back to get anything meaningful without our internal sede instance timing out but I'll give it a shot.